# How to change terminal folder font color

Tags: terminal, font, color, fish

I use terminal with the fish shell. I played the themes and colors in `fish_config` as well as the ANSI colors in the terminal preferences. Nothing I do can change the folder font colors. How do I get rid of this ugly purple-blue color?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The colors are defined by `LSCOLORS`, see `man ls` for details.

```
LSCOLORS The value of this variable describes what color to use for which attribute 
         when colors are enabled with CLICOLOR.  This string is a concatenation 
         of pairs of the format fb, where f is the foreground color and b is the 
         background color.

         The color designators are as follows:

                       a     black
                       b     red
                       c     green
                       d     brown
                       e     blue
                       f     magenta
                       g     cyan
                       h     light grey
                       A     bold black, usually shows up as dark grey
                       B     bold red
                       C     bold green
                       D     bold brown, usually shows up as yellow
                       E     bold blue
                       F     bold magenta
                       G     bold cyan
                       H     bold light grey; looks like bright white
                       x     default foreground or background

         Note that the above are standard ANSI colors.  The actual display may differ
         depending on the color capabilities of the terminal in use.

         The order of the attributes are as follows:

                       1.   directory
                       2.   symbolic link
                       3.   socket
                       4.   pipe
                       5.   executable
                       6.   block special
                       7.   character special
                       8.   executable with setuid bit set
                       9.   executable with setgid bit set
                       10.  directory writable to others, with sticky bit
                       11.  directory writable to others, without sticky bit

         The default is "exfxcxdxbxegedabagacad", i.e. blue foreground and default
         background for regular directories, black foreground and red background for setuid
         executables, etc.
```

To change the dark blue to cyan use

```
export LSCOLORS="gxfxcxdxbxegedabagacad"
```